# Why am I getting a ServerContext.Current error using Excel Web Services?

Tags: 2007, excel-services, error

We are trying to setup Excel Web Services in SharePoint 2007 and for some reason all accounts are getting an error. When I check the event logs, I see the following error:

> ExcelServerSharedWebApplication.Local: Could not get ServerContext.Current, which indicates that either SharePoint or the SSP infrastructure isn't provisioned correctly or that we're running outside of a web context.

I am stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Trusted File Location(s) in the Shared Service Provider in Central Admin?